# using crawler4j for html file on file system

Tags: java, web-crawler

I am trying to use `edu.uci.ics.crawler4j` lib to crawl pages from a html file in my local directory. `C:/work/temp/test.html` is its path.

I found that crawler4j is making Http connection. But for this case there is no need for Http connection. I also prefixed file path with `file://` like `"file:///C:/work/temp/test.html" (which is accessible)`

From the code of PageFetcher class:

```
    SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
    schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", 80, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));

    if (config.isIncludeHttpsPages()) {
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", 443, SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));
    }
```

Is there any way to register `file://` protocol in SchemeRegistry in PageFetcher of crawler4j or
crawler4j is always used for hosted files on a server?

Answer (score 0):

It should be your localhost URL. For example, localhost:80/ should be the root of your directory. The URL should be something like `http://localhost:80/.......`